# Unable to create unique key constraint

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a simple entity and trying to persist it to Oracle database. Here is my enitity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_FLIGHT", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "flight_number", columnNames = {
        "comp_prefix", "flight_number" }))
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    private Long id;
    private String companyPrefix;
    private String number;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCompanyPrefix(String companyPrefix) {
        this.companyPrefix = companyPrefix;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }   

    @Column(name = "comp_prefix")
    public String getCompanyPrefix() {
        return companyPrefix;
    }

    @Column(name = "flight_number")
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Here is my Java class that creates an instance of this entity and saves it to database using Hibernate:

```
public class AppTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Flight flight = new Flight();
        flight.setCompanyPrefix("prefix");;
        flight.setNumber("100");
        flight.setId(1L);
        session.save(flight);

        session.getTransaction().commit();          

        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

When I run this program then I am getting an exception as :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (comp_prefix, flight_number) on table TBL_FLIGHT: database column 'comp_prefix', 'flight_number' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(Configuration.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(Configuration.java:1614)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1450)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
```

Please help where I am making mistake in this code. I am using `Hibernate-4.3.6`

Update: Here is my hibernate configuration file, the table gets generated by hibernate itself:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myuser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypasswd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="org.hibernate.tutorial.Flight" />
</session-factory>
```

Also if possible please suggest me a good resource for Hibernate-4.3, because the [online document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/index.html) is not a good resource for starters like me.

Comment: Could you please post the DDL of your table?

Comment: @Teh, I have configured hibernate to generate the table for me when I run the program, I have added the hibernate.cfg.xml file to my post, please check.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and it was solved by explicitly setting `@Column(name = "field_name")`
to the properties used in `@UniqueConstraint`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using field access strategy (determined by @Id annotation). Put any JPA related annotation right above each field instead of getter property

> As a JPA provider, Hibernate can introspect both the entity attributes
>   (instance fields) or the accessors (instance properties). By default,
>   the placement of the @Id annotation gives the default access strategy.
>   When placed on a field, Hibernate will assume field-based access.
>   Placed on the identifier getter, Hibernate will use property-based
>   access

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears with me when i was trying to create a unique constraint on columns "a_id" and "b_id" on Class A and i was not annotating B with @ManyToOne so Hibernate doesn't know anything about the column "b_id" (as foreign key of class B) :

```
   @Entity
   @Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "a_id", "b_id" }) })
   Class A {
      @Id
      a_id;

      // @ManyToOne was not annotated
      B b;
   }

   @Entity
   Class B {
      @Id
      b_id
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The full error text is:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (comp_prefix, flight_number) on table TBL_FLIGHT: database column 'comp_prefix', 'flight_number' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)

You have most likely misspelled one of the column names.

Comment: The column name annotations are the same though.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, I have updated my post with hibernate configuration file. The table is generated by hibernate itself, and also as per my entity I am using correct column names.

Comment: Adding the @Column annotation at field level instead of method level has solved the issue. I have prepared this simple program by following the hibernate online documentation. It seems the documentation is not complete or has some bugs, can you please suggest how to learn hibernate - 4.3?

Comment: Your solution sounds useful - post it as an answer so others can benefit (it's fine to "answer your own question"). As for learning, I would start with google, but nothing surpasses experience - just use it as much as you can.