# Hibernate Unable to Create Unique Key Constraint

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an application which uses Hibernate to access database. It throws an error as like that:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/XXX/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (column1, column2) on table TABLE: column1, column2 not found
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:273)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (column1, column2) on table TABLE: column1, column2 not found
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(AnnotationConfiguration.java:616)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:348)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1162)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:720)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
>       ... 27 more

I've checked this question: [org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183017/org-hibernate-annotationexception-unable-to-create-unique-key-constraint) and [Unable to create unique key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221929/unable-to-create-unique-key-constraint) however they did not solve my problem.

Is there any idea how to figure out the problem?

Comment: Share your beans file where you define schema of table in hibernate.

Comment: see whether you have misspelled column names in your entity bean

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the database-level column names for the columnNames property of a @UniqueConstraint. For example, whilst for simple types the database-level column name may be the same as the entity-level property name, this is often not the case for relational properties.For example

```
@Table(name = "persons",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"number", "person_type" ,"company_id"})
        })

public abstract class Person extends BaseEntity implements ActorProfile {

    @Column(name = "zpa_number")
    private String zpaNumber;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private Long number;

    @Column(name = "person_type")
    private String personType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

Comment: I had a property empId, in my case it worked with property name not with db column (emp_id). Whereas for the other field in superclass it accepts only db column name. I am confused by this double standard of hibernate now

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a typo in the definition of that UniqueKey, because the columns the constraint should apply to aren't found in the database (which I assume is getting constructed by hibernate).

Beware that you have to use column names and not property names when specifying a unique key constraint.